# Data table and any function

Tags: r, datatable, any

I have 3 variabes (`world`, `place` and `group`). There are 3 groups: 1,2 and 3. If any of the group observations has an observation with `place==1`, then I want to mark all the observations of that `group` as `TRUE`. I have been trying to use the function `any` and the inside data table join `J` but it has not worked. Can anyone explain why and how to do it?

Intended output: group 2 has no observation with `place == 1`, so `place1_group` should be `FALSE`. The other groups should have `place1_group` as `TRUE`.

```
df2 <-structure(list(world = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
                                         4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF"), class = "factor"), 
                     place = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
                     group = c(1,1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("world", "place","group"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- data.table(df2)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df2, group)

# Two step approach
df2[,place1:=FALSE][place==1,place1:= TRUE]
df2[,place1_group := FALSE][any(place1), place1_group := TRUE, by = group] # Not working, place1_group TRUE for all but it should be FALSE for group==2


# Inside join approach
df2[,test := "No place 1"][J(any(place1),by=group),test:="Yes Place 1", by=group] # Why it does not work for group 3?
```

Comment: In the above code, you are putting `any` inside the `i` argument, not the `j` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2[,place1_group:=any(place==1),group][]
#     world place group place1_group
#  1:    AB     1     1         TRUE
#  2:    AC     1     1         TRUE
#  3:    AD     2     1         TRUE
#  4:    AD     2     2        FALSE
#  5:    AD     3     2        FALSE
#  6:    AF     3     2        FALSE
#  7:    AB     1     3         TRUE
#  8:    AE     2     3         TRUE
#  9:    AC     3     3         TRUE
# 10:    AE     1     3         TRUE
```

Comment: why the final chain brackets? What do they mean?

Comment: @user3507584 They print the results.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dplyr` for this:

```
df.new <- df2 %>%
          group_by(group) %>%
          mutate(tf = any(place == 1))
```

This should mark the entire group as either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

You may also have to

```
df.new <- data.table(df.new)
```

Comment: This works but I picked the data.table one as I think it is shorter/better programming.